# Adding tooltips to combobox items

Tags: c#, wpf

So I was wondering if it's possible. I know you can do it in XAML, but I'm adding the combobox items programmatically so that isn't a possibility.

Comment: can you set the tooltip at the changed event for the combobox?

Comment: I need to add tooltips to all items in the drop-down list.

Comment: The comboboxItem class has a Tooltip property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It misses details in your question (part of code), but I will try to answer it because I can not add a comment.

If you add your item by code behind, you can add a tooltip like this :

```
ComboBoxItem it = new ComboBoxItem();
it.Content = "Text in list";
it.ToolTip = "your tooltip text";
cb.Items.Add(it);
```

In this case, cb is your combobox

If you can use this solution, can you tell how you add your item in your combobox ?

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Before I just used comboBox.Items.Add(exampleString)